# Create docker volume directly via VSCode

Tags: memory, docker, visual-studio-code

What is the best way to create docker volume in VSCode? I thought I could've create one with `CTRL+SHIFT+P` and then writing `Docker Volumes: Create`. For me, it is just weird it does not exist. I know I can create one via the command line, but it is always practice to do it directly via VSCode. Otherwise, do you have a workaround?

Comment: Do you have the VS Code Docker extension installed?

Comment: @DanielB Yes, I do.